# concat columns and then convert to date and finally compare in DB2 (IBM as400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a db similar to the picture. I want to have the data from three days ago from the current day. 
 I suppose that I have to concat the three columns and then convert to date for finally compare with the current day.  I tried this:

```
select * from MYTABLE where date(concat("-",concat("-",MYTABLE.YEAR,MYTABLE.MONTH),MYTABLE.DAY))>= CURRENT DATE -3
```

I don't know if it is correct, because I'm connected to IBM as400

Help me please

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Note that data is not similar in their structure.

Comment: You should tag [db2-400] when asking about SQL and IBMi and please paste your data as text.

Comment: If YEAR MONTH and DAY are char or varchar column and year begins with 0 like the fourth one does then no it will not work, the date function will return null, so what are the types of the 3 columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the data matches the example you posted, the following should be enough to do the job:

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where date(trim(ltrim(YEAR, '0')) || '-' || lpad(trim(MONTH), 2, '0') || '-' || lpad(trim(DAY), 2, '0')) >= current_date - 3 days
```

Comment: Thanks @Player1st, only in the end I had to put:  ..... >=current date - 3 days

Comment: Oops.  I must have missed that when I did copied my answer into Stackoverflow.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I get the below error when I try this: 
SQL0181: Value in date, time or timestamp string is not valid

Comment: @sun2 Your data set probably has some data that doesn't match the format of the example question.  There's a reason I caveated my answer with needing all of the data to match the example posted.